# How to prove the irreducible non-negative matrix has positive geometric sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Here is a question:
A matrix $A=(A_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is called *irreducible* iff for every pairs $(i,j)$ we have $(A^k)_{ij}>0$ for some $1\leq k\leq n-1$.

> How to prove that matrix $A$ is irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ $I+A+A^2+\cdots+A^{n-1}>0$ ?

I searched many books but I did not find the proof.

Comment: Linear combinations of positive numbers by positive scalars are positive. Adding positive numbers together gives you positive numbers as well. See if you can structure that into a proof of your own.

Comment: This seems like an exercise you might have been expected to attempt to reinforce your understanding of the definition, but you've posed the problem with no context.  One place to start on propositions that are "if and only if" is with some triage to tell whether one direction is easier than the other.  Another idea would be to try small examples, like $2\times 2$, to see if there is an easy counterexample.  There are lots of ways to add context and avoid the impression of simply passing through an assignment without digesting the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For a list of non-negative numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$, it holds that $a_k > 0$ for at least one value of $k$ if and only if $a_1 + \cdots + a_n > 0$.

The $i,j$ entry of the sum is given by
$$
[I]_{ij}+[A]_{i,j}+[A^2]_{i,j}+\cdots+[A^{n-1}]_{i,j}
$$

Comment: Sorry. I could only figure out (I+A)^m is positive for some large m based on your hint. But I still failed to down to the finite geometric sum.

Comment: @Faber I've added a further hint.

Comment: @Faber It's strange to me that you would be able to figure one out but not the other. How did you deduce that the positivity of $(I + A)^m$ is equivalent, then?

Comment: Thank you. I thought about things morecomplicated than it should be.

Comment: Glad to help.${}{}$

Comment: binomial expansion and take very large m